# UICollectionView Reload doesn't call delegate

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

I have a `UICollectionView` that's connected to myclass `datasource` and `delegate`. When I call `[self.collectionview reloaddata]` it works normally but after a while (random time and number of times) when I reload the collection again it doesn't work any more.

collection reference delegate and datasource are correctly defined.

```
self.devicesCollectionViewDataSource= devices;

self.devicesCollectionView.delegate = self;

self.devicesCollectionView.dataSource = self;

[self.devicesCollectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: Add more code please.

Comment: "After awhile" and "random time" is probably very hard for you to debug. Imagine how hard it is for users who don't know what the rest of your code looks like? 1) How do you know they delegate and datasource methods aren't getting called (do you have log statements in them?) 2) Is it possible that under some circumstance your setting the delegate and datasource to something else after it initially works?

Comment: `self.collectionview` in the first paragraph, but `self.devicesCollectionView` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the `setDelegate` method of your collection view subclass, set a breakpoint and observe who's changing it.

```
-(void)setDelegate:(id<YOUR_PROTOCOL>)delegate {
    _delegate = delegate; // breakpoint here -> look at the trace log, it should give you the caller that's overwriting your delegate

}
```

Clarification: this doesn't solve your problem per se, but at least you know where to look